# Нейронные сети на Python для "чайника"

Tags: python, книги, нейронные-сети

Часто встречаю такое понятие, как нейронные сети и, учитывая еще и тот факт, что потихоньку изучаю Python, то возникла потребность "что-то эдакое" попробовать самому написать, но более менее встречающаяся литература в сети, слишком "тверда и не по зубам" для меня. А ведь так захватывающе - попробовать!

Вопрос: есть ли ресурс, где есть простенькие примеры на Python, для "блондинки с чайником в руках"? В общем буду признателен всем, кто может посодействовать.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Есть куча книг по машинному обучению и нейронным сетям.
[Machine Learning: an Algorithmic Perspective](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415092827/http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781420067187) - пример того, что Вам нужно.

И почему у нас принято только о нейронных сетях вспоминать? Но в этой книге есть среди прочих [пример реализации нейронной сети на Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20190123055521/http://seat.massey.ac.nz:80/personal/s.r.marsland/Code/9/kmeansnet.py).

Посмотрите [пост на хабре с практическим примером](https://habr.com/en/post/67194/).

Вам полезно ещё познакомиться с [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

Есть Python-библиотеки, в которых много чего уже написано. Например, всем известный [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/).

Еще некоторые:

- [ffnet](https://ffnet.sourceforge.net/)
- [neurolab](https://web.archive.org/web/20160327161150/https://code.google.com/p/neurolab/)
- [PyNN](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220045908/http://neuralensemble.org/trac/PyNN/)
- [pylibneural](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibneural/)

Есть хорошая [библиотека машинного обучения](https://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/), которую использую сам, но она не содержит нейронных сетей.

Answer (score 7):

Почитайте книгу "Программируем коллективный разум", думаю вам понравиться.

Comment: читал Тоби Сегарана,и не раз,он и толкнул меня на поиски

Comment: Хм Ну если вы его осилили, то в чем проблема осилить более трудную литературу?

Comment: читать и осилить - это две разные вещи,прочитать-прочитатал,но не осилил,поэтому и начал искать попроще

Comment: Ну вообще это самая простоя книга которые я видел(сам с нее начинал). Так что советую ее все же осилить.

Comment: ну может,все-таки найдется где-нибудь на просторах и попроще,ну а вдруг?

Comment: Так чтобы с практическими примерами ничего лучше не видел. А теория как-то слишком оторвана от программирования.

Answer (score 5):

Для начинающих появился бесплатный курс на Stepic [Нейронные сети](https://stepic.org/course/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-401) в данном курсе используется язык python.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Я четко и ясно ответил на поставленный вопрос: "есть ли ресурс, где есть простенькие примеры на Python, для "блондинки с чайником в руках"?". Коротко, вопрос - есть ли **ресурс**, ответ - ссылка на **ресурс**. Если я что-то не понимаю, то приведите пример, как отвечать на данный вопрос.