# Классификация текста

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, классификация

Доброе время суток всем. Есть текст(сообщения) и нужно их классифицировать.
Например это подходит:

> Добрый вечер.Ищу мастера макияжа на воскресенье. Спасибо.
>
> Сегодня вечером нужно установить тв на стену  Помогите мастера
> ????)))))
>
> Добрый день!Уважаемые родители, подскажите пожалуйста хорошего
> ортопеда!

А вот это уже не подходит:

> Здравствуйте. У нас продаются такие гирлянды ?
>
> Подскажите пожалуйста, где (не обязательно на ЖК) есть хорошее ателье
> .Мне нужно на шубке поменять застежки

1. Нужно понять подходит ли оно вообще, то есть ищут ли какого то человека, мастера. Если что то другое, следовательно оно не подходит.
2. Нужно определить к какому виду относится сообщение, к какой категории, например - медицина, красота, уборка, типо такого.

Я так понимаю нужно создать нейронную сетку с учителем. Скормить ей сообщения такие и поправлять пока более нормально веса не настроятся.
Подскажите пожалуйста может уже где то есть решение данной задачи. Желательно библиотека какая то на python. Чтобы ее научить и она потом верно будет классифицировать текст. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь раздел "classification"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/). Еще почитайте [это](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

Comment: По поводу библиотек и того, что почитать, посмотрите ответы на [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28858/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно создавать нейрононну сеть с 0. Будете очень долго и не факт что успешно изобретать велосипед. В зависимости от изучаемого языка выберете фреймворк и используйте его (советую [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) в связке с [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)). Также советую почитать про NLP и прочесть мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613337/233525/) на похожий вопрос. Так же там есть ссылка на пример от гугла, тоже советую посмотреть.

Comment: Ну а задачу то как решать? Кстати, по поводу TensorFlow http://datareview.info/article/tensorflow-razocharovyivaet-glubokomu-obucheniyu-ot-google-ne-hvataet-glubinyi/

Comment: Задачу решать путем: задал вопрос -> получил ответ что изучать->прошел по ссылкам и изучил. Или вы хотите все готовое и за 5 минут? На счет tensorflow. У каждого свое мнение но хочу отметить что автор сам признается что не эксперт и единомышленников не нашел так что считаю статью бесполезной.