# Как научить нейросетевого чатбота учитывать контекст диалога?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Я немного понимаю что такое нейросеть - математическая модель отражающая реальный мир. Можно научить нейросеть распознавать текст, изображения и т.д. - это понятно. Но я ума не приложу как научить нейросетевого чатбота учитывать контекст диалога?

```
Я: Меня зовут Ваня.
Я: Как меня зовут?
Чатбот: Тебя зовут Ваня.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для учета контекста можно использовать нейросеть типа LSTM (Long Short Term Memory) или просто и по русски - нейросеть с короткой и длинной памятью. Ее суть заключается в том что нейроны этой сети имеют определенный параметр который запоминает о чем идет речь в том или ином предложении. На примере диалога:

```
Я: Меня зовут Ваня. <- нейросеть теперь знает что общается с Ваней
Я: Как меня зовут?
Чатбот: Тебя зовут Ваня.
Я: Сколько мне лет?
Чатбот: Я не знаю, Ваня.

Я: У меня есть друг и его зовут Саша. <- нейросеть теперь знает что теперь речь идет о Саше
Я: Как зовут моего друга?
Чатбот: Твоего друга зовут Саша.

Я: Меня зовут Андрей.
Чатбот: Тебя зовут Андрей. <- нейросеть забывает про Ваню и его друга и менят контекст
```

Конечно как выбирать контекст тоже важно иначе нейросеть не будет знать какие слова в предложении важны а какие нет. Для этого существует NLP (Natural Language Processing) что можно перевести как обработка есстественного языка. Эта техника позволяет определить интонацию предложения, понять о чем идет речь и выделить ключевые слова.

**Дополнение по NLP**

Чтобы понять всю суть NLP советую поиграться с API от гугла по ссылке https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/. Здесь можно вбить предложение, правда пока только на английском и оно выдаст всю информацию о нем. Например если вбить все тоже *"Меня зовут Ваня"*, то гугл пишет что **Ваня** это **человек** и это **парметр** под названием **имя**. Также во вкладке связи можно посмотреть что гугл понял что этот параметр относиться к тому кто пиcал это предложение, то есть ко мне. На вопрос как это работает тут ответить не получиться так как NLP это целая наука.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для реализации чат-ботов используют не только нейронные сети, но и другие алгоритмы машинного обучения. Одной нейронной сетью действительно трудно обойтись. Привожу [статью с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/281459/) в тему.
Есть хороший [фреймворк от microsoft](https://dev.botframework.com/) для создания своих чат-ботов, самое то, если нужно сделать чат-бота без погружения в машинное обучение

Comment: Извините, а какие еще технологии используются для анализа контекста?

Comment: мне все же кажется, что статья про API, а не про то, что там под капотом. Хотелось бы узнать как оно работает, какие там "уравнения"

Answer (score 0):

Я не работал с нейронными сетями, но для любой системы будут работать два условия выясняющими это наверняка:

1. определение по ключевым словам или фразам
2. перед диалогом нужно спросить о чем будет идти речь

а так же к этому можно подключить вероятности которые получаются из истории общения в которой были точные указания на предметную область. Но при этом есть шанс ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Нейросеть это не математическая модель отражающая реальный мир. Хотя бы просто потому, что мы сами не понимаем, что такое реальный мир, что такое разум и не можем объяснить работу мозга. Нейросеть это набор пороговых сумматоров с нелинейной функцией активации и с весовыми коэффициентами связей, по сути математический аппарат работы с большими матрицами данных со встраиваемыми алгоритмами оптимизации. В основном используются для решения задач классификации.
Задача хранения контекста может решаться разными способами например уже упомянутый lstm.
В любом случае никакого интеллекта и разума здесь нет и никогда не будет.

Comment: Вопрос был о другом